# Is there an Arch community repository system for Debian?

Tags: debian, package-management, packaging

I'm looking for a way of having my package searchable by other Debian users from the command line. I don't want to go through the process of having to get a sponsor. Is there some kind of community repo where I could self publish it to like Arch has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.
You could create you own repository, like many projects do. But that alone won't help your visibility.